# Changing the schedule for a Supplier function in a spring cloud kafka example

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to modify the example sender in this [Spring Cloud Stream tutorial](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/stream-developer-guides/streams/standalone-stream-kafka/) to change the default sending interval.

The [example was updated](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/commit/2b3d2b63204c4a20ac8d813ea33c5fa87241c528#diff-bb9524a15fb0301e3fe97ebb2c315b14) to use a functional `Supplier` & removed the `@EnableScheduling\@Scheduled` annotations, but I can't figure out how to change the schedule interval in the new version - this is what I tried unsuccessfully:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class UsageDetailSender {

    private String[] users = {"user1", "user2", "user3", "user4", "user5"};

    @Bean
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 3000)
    public Supplier<UsageDetail> sendEvents() {
        return () -> {
            UsageDetail usageDetail = new UsageDetail();
            usageDetail.setUserId(this.users[new Random().nextInt(5)]);
            usageDetail.setDuration(new Random().nextInt(300));
            usageDetail.setData(new Random().nextInt(700));
            return usageDetail;
        };
    }
}
```

How can I modify the returned Supplier to update every 3s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide poller configuration properties.

See docs here: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_polling_configuration_properties

So, for your `every 3s` it could be like this:

```
spring.cloud.stream.poller.fixedDelay=3000
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I had found a couple of links suggest I use `spring.integration.poller.fixed-delay` which did not work for me, eg this one https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/15/simple-event-driven-microservices-with-spring-cloud-stream

Comment: Yeah... There is no such an option for Spring Integration. Only the one opinionated for Spring Cloud Stream